# Multiple strings in one variable

Tags: python

Say, for example, I have some code that goes like this:

```
sentence = input("Enter input: ")
target_letter = "a" or "b" or "c"
print(sentence.index(target_letter))
```

My main aim is to get the program to print **any** of the target letters' minimum index in the sentence. However when the Boolean "or" operators are used here it only recognizes the **first** string in the variable. For example: If I type

> Ice cream

The program should recognize the 'c' as the first valid string in the index and print "1" but it skips to 'a' and prints "7".

The same sort of problem arises with the "and" operator:

```
sentence = input("Enter input: ")
target_letter = "a" and "b" and "c"
print(sentence.index(target_letter))
```

This time the program only recognizes the **last** string in the variable instead, if I type:

> Exactly

The program throws back "3" becuase c's index is 3 but the first letter is actually 'a' with index 2. And when the input had only a "b" in it out of the strings, the program threw an error because it was neither the first string or the last string.

How would this problem be fixed so that I could place multiple possible strings in a variable so that one of the strings in the variable would be recognized later in the program?

Comment: you tagged this "basic" but it looks like python, and that is not how the boolean operators work.  in both cases you're setting target_letter to the single value that passes the boolean tests, not a set of values as you seem to be wanting

Comment: try typing `"a" or "b" or "c"` at a python prompt and see what happens

Comment: Put the target letters in a list, then loop through the list to try and get each `target_letter`'s index in the sentence?

Comment: `print([sentence.index(target) for target in "abc"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's examine the `target_letter = "a" or "b" or "c" first`.

```
>>> target_letter = "a" or "b" or "c"
>>> target_letter  # will always return 'a' because 'a' is true. 
'a'
>>> #  The only string which will return false is the empty string '' or "".
```

A proposed solution

```
sentence = input("Enter input: ")
target_letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
for letter in sentence:
    if letter in target_letters:
        print(letter, 'was found at location in ',sentence.index(letter))
    else:
        print(letter, "was not found in sentence,", sentence)
```

Output

```
Enter input: Ice creeam
I was not found in sentence, Ice creeam
c was found at location in  1
e was not found in sentence, Ice creeam
  was not found in sentence, Ice creeam
c was found at location in  1
r was not found in sentence, Ice creeam
e was not found in sentence, Ice creeam
e was not found in sentence, Ice creeam
a was found at location in  8
m was not found in sentence, Ice creeam

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a regular expression that matches any of those characters.

```
import re
pattern = r'[abc]' # define regex that matches 'a' OR 'b' OR 'c'
sentence = 'Exactly'
m = re.search(pattern, sentence)
if m:
    print(m.start())
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your description, I guess, this should help.

```
sentence = input("Enter input: ")
for i in sentence:
    if i in "abc":
        print(i, " : ", sentence.index(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using `next` and a generator expression along with `enumerate`.

```
>>> s = "ice cream"
>>> next((i for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in "abc"), None)
1
```

`enumerate` gives us the index as we iterate over the string. The generator returns indices where the corresponding character is *in* `"abc"`. Then we call `next` to get the first match or `None` is a match is not found.