# How do you store a list of strings in an index function?

Tags: python

```
sentence = input("Input sentence: ")
punctuation = [" ", ",", ".", ":", "?", "!"]
interruption1 = sentence.index(punctuation)
word1 = sentence[:interruption1]
print(word1)
```

In this question, the main aim is to have the program print the first word that the user types by identifying a character that implies the first word has ended (the punctuation characters in the 'punctuation' variable). I want the program to accept the 'punctuation' variable within the index function but it sends an error message saying "must be str, not list". I tried for loops, they don't work here either as far as I know.

[A previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75036562/multiple-strings-in-one-variable) gave me information that you can't use boolean values to represent a set of values in a variable, so I used a list, but now this error happens, and there is absolutely nothing on the Internet on this sort of problem (neither do I have an IT teacher or any friends that do Python), so I had to come here after about an hour of trying random combinations of code. How do I make Python accept the list and use it inside the index function? Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a job for a regular expression. Also, to directly answer your question: If a function or method is designed to take a certain type of argument, you can't somehow force that argument type into it. You simply have to use the tools as they were designed. Learning which of those tools to use in what situation is part of the learning process.

Comment: "Trying random combinations of code" is not a maintainable strategy to learn a language. And you can't keep asking question after question, this just doesn't scale. Find a good tutorial and read it. If you already know how to program, [the official tutorial is alright](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). There are many tutorials aimed at people who are also beginners at programming in general. You don't need a teacher or friend: you need structured knowledge (i.e. a tutorial).

Comment: Write out how you'd solve this by hand first - how would you do it if someone gave you a list of characters that could end a sentence? You'd start with the first one, check if that's present, then the next one, check if that's present, etc. That's represented by a for-loop: `for character in punctuation:`; how do you check if it is present? `sentence.index()` - but you have to give it the _character_ (string) to check for, not the whole list.

Comment: I already watched a 5 hour tutorial on YouTube and I learnt a lot from it but not this

Comment: Admittedly I'm not among the youngest users around, so to speak, but I find video tutorials to be utter garbage. And you can't learn a language in 5 hours of watching a half-clueless person typing stuff. You need a book. You need time. You need practice, provided by step-by-step exercises _of a good tutorial_. If you keep doing what you're doing you're setting yourself up for failure and frustration (and a question ban on Stack Overflow). Learning before doing is an investment. You really should invest.

Comment: When you looked at the [documentation for str.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) did it imply that it would accept a list for an argument?

Comment: The advice Andras gave you is good, please start following any decent tutorial, whether book, blog or video. To restate your question more clearly: you want to split the string `sentence` at the first occurrence of any of the strings " ", ",", ".", ":", "?", "!". There are many ways to do this, regular expressions are the best way. You could use for-loops; don't say things like "for loops don't work here either as far as I know"; you mean "I don't understand how to do this using for-loops"; post the non-working code you tried and the error message, to help identify your misunderstanding.

Comment: You *don't* want to "store" the list of strings `punctuation` inside the `str.index()` function. You intend to *pass* a list of strings into `str.index()`. But as @wwii pointed out, `str.index(sub, ...)` expects a single string, so `str.index()` isn't a great function  for trying to match multiple alternatives. So don't use `srt.index`, use regular expressions, they're ideal for this. So please go read any good Python tutorial on regular expressions and start typing and experimenting with it. Then you'll learn how to solve this.

Comment: And a meta-tip on telling good tutorials/blogs/books from bad ones, severely distrust Google's top-ten hits, since they're cluttered with paid SEO-boosted results that try to sell you $$ bootcamps, video courses, tutorials, certifications... Ignore that stuff, especialy if noone cites them unless they're a paid affiliate or shill. Look at tutorials that are mentioned by real developers, preferably in an advertising-free forum, or here on SO. Stuff written by real developers who aren't trying to sell you something.

Comment: If we're being specific: there's a few tips at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use an index unless it is demanded; just keep accepting characters from the sentence until you come to a punctuation. So the simplest looping approach is:

```
sentence = input("Input sentence: ")

punctuation = [" ", ",", ".", ":", "?", "!"]

result = ""
for c in sentence:
    if c in punctuation:
        break
    else:
        result = result + c

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest this is something you should do with regular expressions. But, that doesn't really answer your question, so - you are close, but your problem is that you're passing a list of strings instead of a single string, as your error message implies.

You should loop through each string in the list and get the first occurrence of the string in your sentence. You can use `str.index()` but I prefer to use `str.find()` which will return a -1 if the character is not found thus we don't have to mess around with error exceptions.

```
sentence = input("Input sentence: ")
punctuation = [" ", ",", ".", ":", "?", "!"]

matches = []

for character in punctuation:
    match = sentence.find(character)

    #If the character is found, save to a separate list. 
    #No match means value is -1, so ignore it using >0 

    if match >0:
        matches.append(match) 

# Now find the match that occurs first:

first_match_index = min(matches)

# Return first word

first_word = sentence[:first_match_index]
print(first_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make Python accept the list and use it inside the index function?

You can't [str.index only](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) accepts str.

> I tried for loops, they don't work

A for loop could work

- iterate over `sentence` **while keeping track of the index**
- for each character check to see if it **is in** `punctuation`

  - if it isn't in `punctuation`

    - continue with the next character
  - if it is in `punctuation`

    - use the index to extract the first word using a slice: `sentance[:index]`
    - stop iterating